# Postgres pivot results with no unique identifier to group by

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm having a little trouble pivoting this query... Usually there is an identifier or something common to group the data, but in this particular case there isn't, any help is appreciated!

lets say i have a sample table like so

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id text primary key,
    created_at date not null default CURRENT_DATE
);

INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES
('AS00334455'),
('AS009988'),
('AS0011223'),
('AS00908800'),
('PS00555555'),
('PS00333333'),
('PS00444444');
```

visually it would look like this

```
|         id | created_at |
|------------|------------|
| AS00334455 | 2018-07-05 |
|   AS009988 | 2018-07-05 |
|  AS0011223 | 2018-07-05 |
| AS00908800 | 2018-07-05 |
| PS00555555 | 2018-07-05 |
| PS00333333 | 2018-07-05 |
| PS00444444 | 2018-07-05 |
```

I'd like to select results from this table where i get the ID column pivoted by the first 2 characters of the ID. visually that would look like this

```
|         AS |         PS |
|------------|------------|
| AS00334455 | PS00555555 |
|   AS009988 | PS00333333 |
|  AS0011223 | PS00444444 |
| AS00908800 |            |
```

what i tried so far was this, but im stuck on what group by to apply to render the results appropriately

```
SELECT
  MAX(case when t.id_type = 'AS' then t.id else '' end) as AS,
  MAX(case when t.id_type = 'PS' then t.id else '' end) as PS
FROM
(  SELECT LEFT(id, 2) as id_type, id
   FROM test
) as t;
```

I could probably use a row count and nest inside another select, but im concerned about performance as the real table is already a few million records and there are a lot of other things happening in this query. So optimization is key

[**Fiddle to play around with**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fb964/7)

Comment: I'm far from an expert on `crosstab`, but I think you can use it here.  I have no idea how the performance is.  Here is a really good crosstab example [PostgresSQL Crosstab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Comment: @BShaps thanks, I had already considered crosstab but the issue with it is you can only pivot one piece of data, you have to do a whole other crosstab query for the next column you want to pivot which doesn't seem ideal

Comment: `('AS', 'PS')` are the only types? or you need a dynamic filter?

Comment: There will be 4 types but they are fixed/known

Comment: Can you add a column to include that type? I mean that is the best way to optimize the pivot. Otherwise I will have to create the column on the fly and wont be as fast.

Comment: Already planning to do that, I'm inheriting an existing database but optimizing a lot of slow queries and making schema changes to supplement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one option **[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/64431/4)**:

```
WITH cte as (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(id, 2) ORDER BY id) as rn,
         LEFT(id, 2) as id_type, id             
  FROM test  
)
SELECT MAX( CASE WHEN id_type = 'AS' THEN id END) as "AS",
       MAX( CASE WHEN id_type = 'PS' THEN id END) as "PS"
FROM cte
GROUP BY rn
ORDER BY rn
;
```

OUTPUT

```
|         AS |         PS |
|------------|------------|
|  AS0011223 | PS00333333 |
| AS00334455 | PS00444444 |
| AS00908800 | PS00555555 |
|   AS009988 |     (null) |
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think this is something i can extend to the rest of my query (I need to pivot like 5 columns). Let me try and get this hooked into the server query and see what i can do.